# "hdfs dfsadmin -report" shows 0 datanodes when failover happens

Tags: kubernetes, hadoop, hdfs

i have setup apache-hadoop NameNode HA on kubernetes.
**3 datanodes**
apache-hadoop-datanode-0
apache-hadoop-datanode-1
apache-hadoop-datanode-2

**2 namenodes**
apache-hadoop-namenode-0
apache-hadoop-namenode-1

**3 journalnodes**
apache-hadoop-journalnode-0
apache-hadoop-journalnode-1
apache-hadoop-journalnode-2

when  **$ hdfs dfsadmin -report** is run first on namenode-0
all 3 datanodes are shown properly under ***LiveNodes***.

then after killing namenode on namenode-0
***namenode-1*** becomes the ***active*** namenode.
now running the **$ hdfs dfsadmin -report** shows 0 datanodes.

**Note**: datanode daemons are running on all datanode pods.

any reason why datanodes are not sending hearbeats to new activeNameNode.

Comment: please don't add the [tag:apache] tag back. Alternatively, explain what this question has to do with Apache httpd (please read the descriptions of the tags that you're using).

Comment: I'm sure there is a reason. And that reason would be in the logs of each 3 those pods. Please share them